# Generate point of view (POV) image inside Digital Surface Model (DSM) or 3D City model

Tags: python, dem, 3d

I'm currently working with **DSMs** (*Digital Surface Models*) and user perspective inside that model.

I'm looking for a Python library, which lets me generate a specific view (from the POV perspective) depending on **coordinates and orientation**.

Let's assume the following conditions:

The user and model have the same coordination frame and I'd like to know what the user sees when he's standing on this model, but I **don't** want to render a 3D model of that perspective, but a 2D view.

It's like the user would take a photo from that point.

The output product should look like this:
[image: The output product should look like this]